# How to design Kafka Produce (partition) to guarantee this partial order when consuming?

Tags: apache-kafka

Here is my case:

## System produces messages to one topic, and there are two kind of messages:

**A. new users messages**

produce: every time any user data changed.

markded as: U1, U2, ... Un.

**B. user attribute metadata change messages**

> e.g: user has two attributes `name`, `email`, then added a custom attribute `profile`.

produce: every time user attribute metadata changed.

marked as: M

## When we consume this topic, we need to guarantee partial orders:

- Same User's data should follow its order.
- consumption of metadata change should always: before consuming user data message after this change, after user data message before this change.

## Example:

message natural order:

(0:U1)->(1:U2)->(2:U1)->(3:U3)->(4:U1)->(5:M)->(6:U1)->(7:U2)->(8:U2)->(9:M)->(10:U1)

accepted consuming order:

(0:U1)->(2:U1)->(3:U3)->(1:U2)->(4:U1)->(5:M)->(7:U2)->(6:U1)->...

## The question

If there is no M in it, I can put different User data into different partitions, to increase throughout, but consider the existence of M's ordering requirement, can I make different partition for this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any kind of user identifier (should be equal for "new users messages" and "user attribute metadata change messages" of the same user and at the same time unique for a particular user) as a key of the Kafka message. That way, the data will get partitioned based on the user identifier and you ensure that the data of one user will go to a single partition while keeping the order. That way you can scale with multiple partitions.

When producing the messages to the topic, make sure to synchronously produce the data, e.g. wait till the first message is received before sending the second.

Comment: Thanks. I can understand the producing order. and The user partition based on user id also make sense. The problem is the "metadata change" part. This message is not related to any user, but applied to all users. (e.g: the user TABLE ADDED a field). So I have to make sure it restrictively before and after some user data. Any suggestion?

Comment: In that case I don't see any simple solution but using only one partition. However, this restriction is based on the data and therefore gives a hint to improve the overall design. From my perspective it is usually not a good idea to have one topic filled with user data and meta data at the same time. What I could think of spontaneously is to separate the user and meta data and do a stream join or work with a schema registry...

Comment: i think of a possible workaround if i really want to use multiple partition: for one metadata change, i produce multiple copied messages to all partitions. when consumer got any copy in any partition, it will do the logic: first time it do the expected process (in my case it call 3rd party api to change metadata), other time just use programming approach to avoid repeat work. is this approach do-able?